# Calling opcua.Node.Attributes returns EOF error

Tags: go, opc-ua

I'm trying to get and return all the nodes of `NodeClass` `Variable` of my OPC UA Simulation Server starting at the root node and going down all folder nodes and object nodes that have childs. I tried to use [browse-example of the gopcua repo](https://github.com/gopcua/opcua/blob/9ba7e84e96413982af1a56edff6f784c2bea75ac/examples/browse/browse.go) but whenever the program gets to `attrs, err := n.Attributes(...)` for the second time, it returns an `EOF` error.

I tried to recreate a minimal example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/gopcua/opcua"
    "github.com/gopcua/opcua/id"
    "github.com/gopcua/opcua/ua"
)

const (
    endpoint   string = "opc.tcp://<ServerAddress>"
    rootNodeId string = "i=85"
)

func browse(c *opcua.Client, n *opcua.Node) error {
    _, err := n.Attributes(ua.AttributeIDNodeClass, ua.AttributeIDDataType)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    browseChildren := func(refType uint32) error {
        refs, err := n.ReferencedNodes(refType, ua.BrowseDirectionForward, ua.NodeClassAll, true)
        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("references: %d: %s", refType, err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("found %d child refs\n", len(refs))
        for _, rn := range refs {
            err := browse(c, rn)
            if err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("browse children: %s", err)
            }
            fmt.Printf("Found a Node: %s\n", rn.ID.String())
        }
        return nil
    }

    if err := browseChildren(id.HasChild); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if err := browseChildren(id.Organizes); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    c := opcua.NewClient(endpoint)
    if err := c.Connect(ctx); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Could not connect")
        panic(err)
    }
    defer c.Close()
    id, _ := ua.ParseNodeID(rootNodeId)
    err := browse(c, c.Node(id))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

This is how the Prosys OPC UA Simulation Server looks like:

[image]

And this the output I get from the program:

```
found 0 child refs
found 5 child refs
2022/01/21 14:26:06 browse children: EOF
exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

#### tl;dr

```golang
browseChildren := func(refType uint32) error {
        refs, err := n.ReferencedNodes(refType, ua.BrowseDirectionForward, ua.NodeClassAll, true)
        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("references: %d: %s", refType, err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("found %d child refs\n", len(refs))
        for _, rn := range refs {
            refNodeID := ua.MustParseNodeID(rn.ID.String())
            refNode := c.Node(refNodeID) // parse the referenced nodes before usage
            err := browse(c, refNode)
            if err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("browse children: %s", err)
            }
            fmt.Printf("Found a Node: %s\n", refNode.ID.String())
        }
        return nil
    }
```

#### Reason

The referenced nodes that are returned by `n.ReferencedNodes` have an invalid `NodeIDType` (64). The only supported `NodeIDType`s are 0-5. Reparsing them gives them a proper `NodeIDType`. (Related Gitlab issue: https://github.com/gopcua/opcua/issues/550)